# Sort a group of associate arrays by one value in each array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, associative-array

I am currently doing a golf scorecard application and I'm looking to sort each players results array by their overall score.

e.g, if I have the following arrays:

```
array1 = {
    name: "player1",
    overall: -3
}

array2 = {
    name: "player2",
    overall: -1
}
```

How can I sort them so that I can output the rank of each player depending on who got the best score while also keeping the name value?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Those are *objects*, not arrays. Make an actual *array* of such objects and sort the array using its `.sort` method (`var players = [{name: ...}, {name: ...}];`).

Answer (score 2):

With a proper data structure for [Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), you can sort them with [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

```js
var object1 = { name: "player1", overall: -3 },
    object2 = { name: "player2", overall: -1 },
    array = [object1, object2];

array.sort(function (a, b) { return a.overall - b.overall; });

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(array, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: OP probably wants them sorted in opposite order, I'm guessing.

Comment: @MarkReed, "*output the rank of each player depending on who got the best score *", more negative value is good ...?

Comment: Yup.  It's golf.  The lower the score, the better.